# Network permissions to non sudo user

Tags: permissions, user-accounts, arch-linux, user-groups

I'm using Arch Linux. I have a few directories that I don't want any user access to. So I've kept it locked with access to `sudo` only.

I have a user "alarm". I don't want "alarm" to access those files, so the user can't run `sudo`. BUT, I want him be able to switch networks, user `netctl`.

How do I give him those permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you refer to giving user a permission to run `sudo` you usually think of giving him permissions to run any command on behalf of the user `root. But`sudoers`file allows much more detailed configuration options that can give permissions to run only one particular command with`root` permissions.

For example add the following to the `sudoers` file (using `visudo`):

```
alarm ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/netctl start wlan0-ssid
```

to limit the scope of `sudo` for user `alarm` just to one specific command with a specified argument: `/usr/bin/netctl start wlan0-ssid`. It will not give this user any more permissions and he won't be able to access any files (as it would required running other commands which are not specified).

Add more lines and customise them to fit your configuration.

Comment: But he would get access to my files that are for sudo access only, right?

Comment: No, user `alarm` would only be able to run the specified command. There is no such thing as "files for sudo access" anyway.

Comment: Is something like this possible without sudo?

Comment: That's what sudo was built for. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: actually i need to restrict access to some files. the whole system is on RPi. So if someone screws the sudoers file by plugging in SD card to PC, I'm screwed